# How do I update Ruby from the default version to 2.1.6 via terminal?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, ruby

I don't want to update my pre-installed Ruby to the latest version.

My question is: how can I upgrade the version of Ruby to version 2.1.6 on Mac via terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [homebrew](http://brew.sh) has moved on to ruby version 2.4.2 you might not have luck installing that far back a version.

I've not used RVM lately, since I'm happy with keeping up with the ruby version that's stable (and let home brew update things since I have no legacy projects needing 2.1), but give the following steps a shot. This will side load another version that's older than what Apple ships.

- https://rvm.io

Once that's installed:

```
 rvm install 2.1.6  
 rvm --default use 2.1.6
```

Comment: Can't up vote mate but this worked.

Comment: @byteme no worries. You did the most important thing - using the check mark to indicate it worked for you!